# Docker Daemon fails to run - containerd will not start

Tags: modules, docker

Fairly new to Linux. Trying to run Docker on a raspberrypi.

```
sudo service docker status

docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.

sudo systemctl list-dependencies docker
```

container.d not started

```
sudo systemctl start containerd.service
● containerd.service - containerd container runtime
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/containerd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-12-05 11:34:57 PST; 1min 30s ago
     Docs: https://containerd.io
  Process: 28488 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe overlay (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 8ms

Dec 05 11:34:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting containerd container runtime...
Dec 05 11:34:57 raspberrypi modprobe[28488]: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/
modules/4.9.80-v7+/modules.dep.bin'
Dec 05 11:34:57 raspberrypi modprobe[28488]: modprobe: FATAL: Module overlay not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.80-v7+
Dec 05 11:34:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: containerd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 05 11:34:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start containerd container runtime.
Dec 05 11:34:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: containerd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 05 11:34:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: containerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

ls /lib/modules/*/modules.dep.bin
/lib/modules/4.14.79+/modules.dep.bin
/lib/modules/4.14.79-v7+/modules.dep.bin
```

So it looks like I have a different version of modules.dep.bin than what it wants? I'm not sure what I do next. How do I fix this? Do I need to update modules.dep.bin?

Docker was installed with:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

Docker version:

```
docker -v
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
```

uname -r:

```
uname -r
4.9.80-v7+
```

Comment: How did you install docker? Did you use a straight `apt install`? Which version is installed? Check with `docker -v` Just to make sure you don't have a kernel discrepancy: can you check the kernel version with `uname -r`?

Comment: Hi, added answers to main text. Respective answers: `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh`; `Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4`; `4.9.80-v7+`

Comment: Your docker install looks OK, but your kernel and libs are a different version. Did you reboot your Pi recently? Try rebooting your Pi and then check if `uname -r` gets updated.

Comment: `uname -r
4.14.79-v7+` post reboot. And started. THANKS!

Comment: Please make an answer to finish your question and to show others that your question is already answered and they do not try to help you for nothing ;-) (like me ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pi was already updated, but I had not rebooted it. The module.bin file was out of sync with uname -r. Upon rebooting, both were at the same version and the docker daemon ran successfully.